# Multi-customer routing in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I've been tasked with creating an ASP.NET Core MVC site in C#.
However, it needs the ability to have branding in order to serve different customers. I understand it will involve some routing configuration and it would be nice to serve different CSS files to different customers.

So, instead of `http://localhost/Home/Index`, which ultimately uses the `Views/Index.cshtml` view, I want something like `http://localhost/Home/Customer01/Index`, EXCEPT I want the URL to be more like `http://www.customer01.com/Home/Index` so customers are not aware of each other.

Where `Index` cannot be found I'd like it to fall back to `Home/Index.cshtml`.

I realize this is bit vague but I don't know where to start. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: sorry, I don't think using Routing to isolate your different customers, I think you'd better to create a new project for new users to make your application more available and esay to scale out.